# String manipulation in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a command but I do not want one long line that looks untidy. I am looking to add the strings together to be executed as on command. I have some code below which is part of an email function:

```
msg = MIMEText("The nightly build status was a SUCCESS\n\nBuild File: http://www.python.org\n\n Build Results File: http://10.51.54.57/sandboxes/", project, "\n")
```

This shows the one line, I am hoping for a better way to do this. I have tried the below code but it does not work.

```
msg = MIMEText("The nightly build status was a SUCCESS\n\nBuild File: ")
msg += MIMEText("http://www.python.org\n\n Build Results File: ")
msg += MIMEText("http://10.51.54.57/sandboxes/", project, "\n")
```

Thanks for any help.

I have tried the below code but get:

```
msg = MIMEText("""The nightly build status was a SUCCESS\n\n
   Build File: """,  
   build_file, """
   \n\n 
   Build Results File: """, 
   build_file, """
   \n\n
   Sandbox Folder:""", 
   sandbox, """ 
   \n\n
   Antibrick File: """,
   antibrick, "\n\n")
```

Now I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_email.py", line 45, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': myObject = email_success()
  File "test_email.py", line 32, in email_success
    antibrick, "\n\n")
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 4 arguments (10 given)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks S.Mark, I tried this but when the email is sent it is not as a hyperlink but sent as:

```
The nightly build status was a SUCCESS


Build File: ('http://10.67.54.57/sandboxes/', '2010-01-05/new_sandbox', 'basebuild') 



Build Results File: ('http://10.67.54.57/sandboxes/', '2010-01-05/new_sandbox', 'basebuild') 



Sandbox Folder: ('http://10.67.54.57/sandboxes/', '2010-01-05/new_sandbox')  



Antibrick File:
```

Comment: Please specify the error you've got.

Comment: Probably that `MIMEText` cannot be concatenated together like that.

Comment: the error says it all!! you have 10 arguments passed to MIMEText. construct your message properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
msg = MIMEText(
"The nightly build status was a SUCCESS\n\n"
"Build File: http://www.python.org\n\n"
"Build Results File: http://10.51.54.57/sandboxes/"
, project
, "\n"
)
```

Or

```
msg = MIMEText("""The nightly build status was a SUCCESS

Build File: http://www.python.org

Build Results File: http://10.51.54.57/sandboxes/""", project, "\n")
```

Or

```
msg = MIMEText("The nightly build status was a SUCCESS\n\n"
"Build File: http://www.python.org\n\n"
"Build Results File: http://10.51.54.57/sandboxes/"
, project, "\n")
```

**UPDATE**: because OP added another question

```
msg=MIMEText("""The nightly build status was a SUCCESS\n\n
    Build File: %s
    \n\n 
    Build Results File: %s
    \n\n
    Sandbox Folder: %s 
    \n\n
    Antibrick File: """ % (build_file,build_file,sandbox),
    antibrick, 
    "\n\n"
)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
msg = MIMEText("""The nightly build status was a SUCCESS

Build File:
http://www.python.org

Build Results File: 
http://10.51.54.57/sandboxes/""", project, "\n")
```

If the additional space at the beginning of each line is a problem, remove them with a regexp (`r'^\s+'`)

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
msg= MIMEText("The nightly build status was a SUCCESS\n\nBuild File: "+ \
  "http://www.python.org\n\n Bu..... ")
```

etc.

(I.e., use the line continuation backslash).

Also note  that the following each give you *abcdef*

```
s ="abc" "def"

s= "abc" \
     "def"
```

Also,

```
 s="""xyz
    wvu"""
```

gives you

```
'xyz\nwvu'
```

Answer (score 1):

Python supports multi-line strings using triple quotes:

```
text = """The nightly build status was a SUCCESS\n\nBuild File: 
http://www.python.org\n\n Build Results File: 
http://10.51.54.57/sandboxes/"""
msg = MIMEText(text, project, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use triple quotes

```
>>> s="""The nightly build status was a SUCCESS

Build File: http://www.python.org

Build Results File: http://10.51.54.57/sandboxes/"""

>>> msg=MimeType(s,project,"\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, what exactly is the module are you using? I am guessing, that it is deprecated, because the modern interface is [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) (if I've guessed your intentions correctly). More specifically, to create a `MIMEText` object you use [this class](http://docs.python.org/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText). The signature is

```
email.mime.text.MIMEText(_text[, _subtype[, _charset]])
```